# Aysnc ActiveMQ Message consumer unable to consume messages

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using a an Async Message Consumer in ActiveMQ. My Producer works just fine and send message to the Queue. Now, my async message consumer is just waiting for the onMessage() to be called on, which never happens. So, the problem is:

- Messages are not consumed by the Async Consumer.
- Messages get piled up in the pending messages for the Queue.

Snapshot of the ActiveMQ log also shows a lot of messages just piled up in the pending state:

```
2015-08-31 09:54:45,331 | DEBUG | queue://SampleQ1, subscriptions=0, memory=0%, size=517, pending=0 <b>toPageIn</b>: 78, Inflight: 0, <b>pagedInMessages.size</b> 439, <b>pagedInPendingDispatch.size</b> 438, enqueueCount: 529, dequeueCount: 12, memUsage:2971237 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Queue:SampleQ1
```

I am unable to figure out where exactly the problem lies.

The counts:

- toPageIn 78
- pagedInMessages.size 439
- pagedInPendingDispatch.size 438

just keeps on increasing and messages remain undelivered to the consumer.

Is it a server side problem or a client side ?

Comment: I think it is a client side issue. Can you please provide some information about how the client is connecting to activemq server?

Comment: Thanks Hemant. I figured out later that the issue was actually at the server i.e. ActiveMQ. Browsing over the ActiveMQ bug list came across a bug that was quite similiar to what I experienced. Summarizing, Queue was unable to deliver messages at random instance in time. The bug mentions the kahaDB going in some inconsistent state causing message delivery to a standstill. However, the configuration `<!--policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" memoryLimit="1mb" useCache="false">
    </policyEntry-->` made our ActiveMQ server behave nicely

Answer (score 1):

Browsing over the ActiveMQ bug list came across a bug that was quite similiar to what I experienced.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-2955

Summarizing, my Queue was unable to deliver messages to my async consumers at random instance in time. Once this event occurs I find a built up of messages in the pending messages and a mismatch in the count of messages enqueued vs messages dequeued.

The bug as mentioned in the link talks of the kahaDB for persistent storage going in some inconsistent state causing message delivery to a standstill. As mentioned in the bug analysis, the ActiveMQ configuration in activemq.xml solves the problem.

```
<!--policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" memoryLimit="1mb" useCache="false">
</policyEntry-->
```